# Is it possible to view the contents of a satellite assembly?

Tags: .net, localization, satellite-assembly

I have what I think are some satellite assemblies in an application produced by a company that no-longer exists.  I'd like to confirm that they are what I think (the naming is correct but...) and see what is inside them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/)

Comment: Thanks, this looks like exactly the sort of tool I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

[.NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) might be your answer.

It's possible that the company has [obfuscated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation) its assemblies, but you will only find out by looking at the disassembled code.

Answer (score 0):

[dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) from JetBrains does also this job